# can't run transition css property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to figure out how does transition work in css. I expect to see smooth width change of images on my example (when I resize the browser window), but it doesn't work. Can you point me on a mistake?

```css
div{
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    width:25%;
    -webkit-transition: width 20s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 20s;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="Paris">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="Paris">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to replace `%` with `vw`

replace `width: 20%;` with `width: 20vw;` Then it works just fine.

```css
div{
 display: inline-block;

}
img {
 width: 20vw;
    -webkit-transition: width 20s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 20s;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="Paris"/>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" alt="Paris"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `You can't use transitions on %.` --> this is false

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, you are right! Its not supported yet, thats the problem. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties-

Comment: no it's well suppoted, but the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I got my info from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311299/css-transition-not-working-for-percentage-height They could be wrong though.

Comment: this question is very very old .. 7 years later

Comment: Hehe, yeah. But read the comment given in the anwser of *fabb*

Comment: @SergeyVladimirovich you accepted the answer but it doesn't anwser why your code is not working, and the % is well supported with transition. Here is a simple example : https://jsfiddle.net/6cy12okv/...so the problem is somewhere else. using vw is a workaround

Comment: Ok, ok, I will update it again. Removing the incorrect information out of the awnser.

Comment: but you still didn't explain anything .. why it works with vw ? can you tell us ? ... i hoped the OP will wait before accepting, maybe someone will have an answer with explanation.